# Number of Elements in a Cyclic Subgroup of $\mathbb C^*$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm stuck on this problem. The question is:

> Find the number of elements in the cyclic subgroup $A$ of $\mathbb C^*$ generated by $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}$.

The solutions says that the answer is simply 8 because $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}$ = $\cos{\frac{2\pi}{8}}$ + $i\sin{\frac{2\pi}{8}}$ is a generator of $A$, but I don't understand where 8 came from. Is it simply trial and error, or is there some intuitive way of getting to 8? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}} = (\cos(\pi/4)+i \sin(\pi/4)) = e^{i\pi / 4}.$$ We have that $$e^{2\pi i} = 1\implies (e^{i\pi/4})^{8} = 1 \implies o(\exp(i\pi/4)) = 8$$

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do it (this is just practice):

$$(1+i)^2=2i\implies\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}\right)^2=i$$

and we know o$(i)=4\;$ , so the generator's order is $\;2\cdot4=8\;$ :

$$\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}\right)^8=\left[\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}\right)^2\right]^4=i^4=1$$